# How to extract audio features in java?

Tags: java, audio

My thesis project is on Audio Feature extraction, their classifcation and comparison.

I am unable to extract the audio features from the last 6months.

I just have an idea that may work.

The audio in any format is to be converted into pcm format and features like bandwidth, Zero Crossing Rate, Noise Frame Ratio, Pitch Strength and mel Frequency Cepctral Coefficients can be extracted from it.
Then a data set is prepared using these features and then various audio classifiaction algoriths are applied to it.

Kindly help how can i proceed further and extract audio features?

Thanx

Comment: Signal processing like that is not really Java-specific, though it is obviously possible.  You may want to consider a different toolset that has native support for some of the things you need to do, like Fourier transforms.  Maybe Matlab?

Comment: Octave is an alternative which may be more accessible for a student

Comment: Sir kindly be specific im new to this field. I have tried to convert any audio format to pcm format in java, but feature extraction is becoming difficult further.

Comment: PCM as you should know is simply linear raw data matching the sample frequency and (un)signed amplitude in a given bit length (most often aligned on the byte).  Are you wanting Java to decode to PCM or DSP pre-existing PCM?

Comment: PCM,as an uncomressed format i think will help me extract required features. So i want to convert any audio format to pcm and then extract the audio features.

Comment: Kindly guide if their is any other method to extract audio features and make a data set of these features.

Answer (score 6):

Although it is a very old post but maybe someone would reach here after googling. Now there are some very good toolkits to use :

1. TarsoDSP https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP
2. OpenSmile http://www.audeering.com/research/opensmile
3. CMU Sphinx

Answer (score 2):

This is probably too late to be of much help, but you should really look at the [jmir](http://jmir.sourceforge.net/index_jAudio.html) project.  It's a system for doing audio feature extraction and classification in Java.  It's all open source and well documented.